# Django Form request method is always GET, even method="POST" is supplied from templated

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am passing two parameters from views to form's **init** method with POST request from form of templates. But It always gets a GET method.
Here is my code :

**views.py**

```
form = formA(team_one=team_one, team_two=team_two)
print(request.method)
if request.method == 'POST':
    team_one = match_obj.first().short_team_one
    team_two = match_obj.first().short_team_two
```

**forms.py**

```
class formA(forms.Form):
    team_one = ""
    team_two = ""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        team_one = kwargs.pop("team_one")
        team_two = kwargs.pop("team_two")
        super(formA, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        obj = Detail.objects.filter(Q(current_one=team_one) | Q(current_two=team_two),)
        for o in obj:
            self.fields[o.name] = forms.BooleanField()
```

**template**

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="submit" name="submit" id="signup" value="Create" style="float:right; right:20px;">
</form>
```

Please HELP!

Comment: try this `form = formA(request.POST or None,team_one=team_one, team_two=team_two)`

Comment: I have tried the request.POST or None, That's too not working. Do I have to pass action also??

Comment: Post more code, possibly the directory structure as well. Also, you didnt define what is the name of function in views. SHow the urls.py as well.